# Spark Streaming Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, databricks

Im trying to Stream data from kafka avro topic.

Below is my code snippet:

```
val sparkStreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(60))
val brokers = "Broker info"
val schemaRegistryURL = "URL schema registry "
val subjectValueName = "topicname" + "-value"
val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)
val valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)
val parser = new Schema.Parser
val topicValueAvroSchema: Schema = parser.parse(valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema)

val kafkaParam = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "streaming-kafka")
kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,  "latest")
kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")

val topicList = List("topicname")
val messageStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(sparkStreamingContext, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicList, kafkaParam))
val TRANSACTION_SCHEMA: StructType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(topicValueAvroSchema).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
messageStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    val streamData = spark.read.schema(TRANSACTION_SCHEMA).avro(rdd.map(x => x.value()).toString())
    streamData.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").mode("Append") saveAsTable ("tablename")
    }
}
sparkStreamingContext.start()
sparkStreamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

But I get below error can some one help to fix this.

```sh
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: MapPartitionsRDD[75] at map at <console>:54
```

Comment: Btw, you should be using String deserializers if you have Avro data, but the error seems to be a configuration problem around the `saveAsTable` call, or you forgot the `http` on the schema registry address

Comment: @cricket_007 Schema registry URL is working fine I can print Schema out of it, Not  sure whats the issue in here  `    val streamData = spark.read.schema(TRANSACTION_SCHEMA).avro(rdd.map(x => x.value()).toString()) ` this is the line which is causing issues.

Comment: Alright, well, I haven't used `.avro` Spark funtions, but I do know they don't work with Schema Registry encoded Avro data